# How to find if a member variable is readonly?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, readonly, fieldinfo

```
class Bla
{
    public readonly int sum;
}

FieldInfo f = type.GetField("sum");
f.??   // what?
```

How do I find if `sum` is readonly or not? For properties I can do `PropertyInfo.CanWrite` to find if the member has write access.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`readonly` means that field assignment can occur only near field declaration or inside a constructor. So you can use `IsInitOnly` property on a `FieldInfo`, which

> Gets a value indicating whether the field can only be set in the body of the constructor

More details are on the [`IsInitOnly` MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.isinitonly.aspx)

```
FieldInfo f = typeof(Bla).GetField("sum");
Console.WriteLine(f.IsInitOnly); //return true
```

Notes: you also can use `IsLiteral` property to test if the field is compiled time constant. It will return false for `readonly` field, but true for fields, marked with `const`.

Another note: reflection doesn't prevent you from writing into `readonly` and `private` field (same is true for `public readonly`, but I want to show a more restricted case). So the next code examples are valid and won't throw any exceptions:

```
class Bla
{
    //note field is private now
    private readonly int sum = 0;
}
```

Now if you get the field and write a value to it (I use `BindingFlags` to get private non-static fields, because `GetField` won't return `FieldInfo` for private fields by default)

```
FieldInfo field = typeof(Bla).GetField("sum", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                              BindingFlags.Instance);

var bla = new Bla();
field.SetValue(bla, 42);

Console.WriteLine(field.GetValue(bla)); //prints 42
```

All works ok. It will throw an exception only if a field is `const`.

Comment: Any idea what `NonPublic` flag is doing here?

Comment: @nawfal `GetField` won't return private fields by default. You need to set this explicitly

Comment: @Oh yes I get it. I had not noticed your example about `private`. Thanks

Comment: +1 for noting that Reflection will not prevent you from writing a `readonly` field (which is completely counter-intuitive).

Comment: @SamGoldberg I agree it's counter-intuitive, but on the other hand it allows ORMs to work, for example, while still having some nice compile-time checks.

Answer (score 2):

`f.Attributes` should contain `FieldAttributes.InitOnly`